# Display inline list vertically in CSS

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

I have a menu I'm trying to make for my webpage that would run off to the right side of it and I' want it to be vertical, but I'm having troubles getting the text to align while it's up and down. I really haven't made any headway on getting it to display right at all, but here's the rotation CSS etc:

```
#rightmenu {
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    width:30px;height:578px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
    border-top-right-radius:10px;
    float:right;
    margin-top:-554px;
}
    #rightmenu p {

    }
    #rightmenu ul {
        width:30px;
        height:20px;
        -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
        -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
        -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
        -o-transform:rotate(90deg);
        font: 18px normal, sans-serif;
        list-style-type:none;
        padding:0;
        
    }
    #rightmenu li {
        display:inline;

    }
```

Here's what the webpage looks like: [image]

I want the 'Home' to be rotated like it is, but to go down in a list. So it would start at the top of the webpage like it is now, but instead of the text being below it, it would be to it's right. Ask if I need to clarify, I'm having troubles explaining.

Comment: So I'm guessing no one knows?

Comment: I'm guessing we're not your personal tech support and when someone wants to address your question, they will.

Comment: Well shiver me timbers, I didn't mean to offend you. Saying 'is this just not possible?' would have been a much better worded version of that, but I'm just curious to see if I either need to start thinking of other options or change the design. Sorry to sound cocky or something =]

Comment: It's not about the wording, it's about impatience and "bumping" the question **an hour** after it was posted.

Comment: What do you mean bumping?

Comment: c'mon @Trickery, down vote it if you don't like the question, but dude let it go...

Comment: @jGanja thanks for the defense, but I'm rather new to stackoverflow so if I can have people calling me out on some mistakes, I can learn better for the future on some things to do or not to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CSS was almost right. I moved the rotation from the `ul` to `li` element and changed some margins/paddings.

Here you go:

```
#rightmenu {
    float:right;
}

#rightmenu ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

#rightmenu li {
    display:block;
    padding: 20px 0px;

    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(90deg);
}
```

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/A3WaD/2/

**UPDATE**
Fixed JS Fiddle, it wasn't updated with the working solution

Comment: Thanks a million! Worked great.

Comment: +1 for an acceptable solution, but you really didn't need to be so nasty about it.